# Laravel aimeos how to add user to group?

Tags: php, laravel

Laravel 5.8
"aimeos/aimeos-laravel": "^2019.04"

I create new user by code:

```
$user = new User([
    'id_customer' => $id_customer,
    'id_customer_ref' => $id_customer_ref,
    'firstname' => $firstname,
    'lastname' => $lastname,
    'email' => $email
]);
```

and save it:

```
$user->save()
```

This I do in a class extended from `Illuminate\Console\Command`.

How can I add this user to some group like editor ?

Answer (score 0):

I would tag this as more of a database question, but basically you'd set up a relationship between the users. The most common method of grouping is simply adding an integer or string to the user table. So create a [migration](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/migrations):

```sh
php artisan make:migration add_types_on_users
```

Then in the Blueprint callback do something like:

```php
$table->string('type')->default('regular');
// or if you want an integer
$table->integer('type')->default(0);
```

Don't forget to add the reverse function logic:

```php
$table->dropColumn('type');
```

Then run the migration:

```sh
php artisan migration
```

Now whenever you want to see if a user has permissions([typically done in policies](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/authorization)) just check that field

```php
if($user->type === 'editor'){
   // do editor only stuff
}
```